# Uploading video files to IIS 7 through php fails

Tags: php, iis-7, upload

I'm trying to get my website to upload video's and pictures. As I have made more websites that upload pictures there is no problem on that front, but when i try to upload a video for some reason it can't be found in the `$_FILES` array that contains an uploaded image.

I have already googled and found stuff about the php.ini file and IIS 7 containing max sizes for uploads. these are all set to 1024M:

In php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
```

In IIS 7:

```
maxAllowedContentLength = 1073741824
maxRequestLength = 1073741824
```

After some testing it appears that really small video files do work (192KB) but somewhat bigger doesnt show anyting in the $_FILES array (11MB) but really big files (80MB) gives an error: `The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.`. The problem is that i have set the `maxAllowedContentLength` to 1GB. So that shouldn't happen?! An image of this is down below:

[Image](http://imageshack.us/f/521/35215750.png/)

[image]

Any help or advice is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP Error 404.13 means that the IIS7 request filtering module is killing the request because the request is too large.

The correct way to increase this is by configuring the `maxAllowedContentLength` value in the  `system.webServer > security > requestFiltering` configuration section of your site's `web.config`.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <!-- Allow 100MB requests -->
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more information see:

> [Request Limits  - IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits)

Comment: Great, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` file and add `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />` to the end of the...

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
```

section

Comment: You should really try to avoid editing the global IIS configuration like that. Instead you should do what the previous answer said and edit only the config for the particular site which needs such large requests. Doing it the way you did exposes other sites you might have running on the server to requests that are much larger than they are expecting.